# Safari overflow hidden border radius drop shadow

Tags: css, overflow, shadow, safari-windows

I have problem with creating round circle in Safari (only on Windows). The problem is that when I apply the fix for safari mentioned elsewhere:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white, black);
```

I loose drop shadow on element:

http://jsfiddle.net/qWdf6/627/

Is there a way to keep drop shadow?

Comment: is there a reason why not to apply border-radius to img too ? http://jsfiddle.net/qWdf6/628/ or even both shadow & radius only to img ?

Comment: I use to tell to cure a bug in IE6 was to avoid condition that brings it up ... any feed back from my previous comment :) ? cause if you have no reason, bug won't show up

Comment: @GCyrillus : this wont work if image is not the same width and height as the wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/qWdf6/629/

Comment: okay , good point, now i understand why you have to go through this. you need some extra markup : http://jsfiddle.net/qWdf6/630/